# Elif Command Not Working Even When It's Response Is Typed

Tags: python

So, I'm quite new to python and I've been trying make a game. It goes as follows.

-Asks for name (Done)

-Returns a username made of the first two letters of each name (Done)

-Asks user to play (Issue is here)

What happens is that it rolls the dice if you pick yes but is meant to give you a simple goodbye when you say no, however when you say no it still rolls the dice and then returns the result and tell you if you've won or not.

Everything else seems to work fine, it's just where even if you type the response to the elif, the if still takes place. If anybody could take a look at this for me I'd be thankful.

```
from random import randint

print ("Hello, whats is your first name?")
first_name = input()
print ("What is your second name?")
second_name = input()
username = first_name[0] + first_name[1] + second_name[0] + second_name[1]
print (username + ", I want to play a game. Do you accept?")
game = input()
if game.lower() == "yes":
print ("Great, let's play. I'm going to roll a dice, if it lands on a 6, you win. If not, you lose.")
dice_roll = (randint(1,6))
print (dice_roll)
if dice_roll == 6:
    print ("Congrats, you win.")
elif dice_roll != 6:
    print ("Sorry. You lose.")
elif game.lower() == "no":
    print ("Fine, leave then.")
```

Comment: Could you provide more details ? As is, your code runs a single time, there's no loop control to replay the game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the logic of rolling the dice inside an `if` statement if the user inputs `yes`. Otherwise, you can branch to an `else` statement and print goodbye.

```
if game.lower() == "yes":
    # Roll dice here
else:
    # Print out goodbye
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an indentation issue with your code. That is why the dice is rolled even if the user typed in something different from `"yes"`

```
from random import randint

print("Hello, whats is your first name?")
first_name = input()
print("What is your second name?")
second_name = input()
username = first_name[0] + first_name[1] + second_name[0] + second_name[1]
print (username + ", I want to play a game. Do you accept?")
game = input()
if game.lower() == "yes":
  print ("Great, let's play. I'm going to roll a dice, if it lands on a 6, you win. If not, you lose.")
  dice_roll = (randint(1,6))
  print (dice_roll)
  if dice_roll == 6:
    print ("Congrats, you win.")
  elif dice_roll != 6:
    print ("Sorry. You lose.")
elif game.lower() == "no":
    print ("Fine, leave then.")
```